# Why are two columns being created for a foreign key?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Let's say I have a product class that has a Category property on it.

```
public class Product : Entity<int> // Base class defines the Id
{
  public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping file is simple

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
  public ProductMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.Category).Nullable();
  }
}
```

Using `SchemaExport.Create` This created two columns in my database, `ProductCategoryId` and `CategoryId`. Given my conventions, only `CategoryId` should exist. Both are nullable, but only `CategoryId` is used. No matter what, `ProductCategoryId` is always null, and it is the column with the foreign key constraint on it.

Why is this? I can't actually find any problems with the code, as far as I can tell everything works fine using the CategoryId column. I can query/save/update with or without a Category. I wouldn't even know the other column existed if I didn't go looking in the database, but I don't like having a column when I don't know what it is for. Is there a reason it is there, or is something wrong with the way I mapped a nullable reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem isn't anything to do  with the `Product` or `ProductMap` class I believe. The issue is with the `ProductCategory` map.

That is what is creating the `ProductCategoryId` column in the database.

```
public class ProductCategoryMap : ClassMap<ProductCategory>
{
    public ProductCategoryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        // Other mappings
        HasMany(x => x.Products).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

This mapping wasn't able to tell that it was supposed to be using the existing `CategoryId` column. Specifying it on the mapping file, or even renaming my `Category` property on the `Product` class to `ProductCategory` forces it to stop creating a different column.